# How to loop through columns of a table and print the CountDistinct of each column in one go

Tags: sql, count, azure-synapse

I am kind of new to SQL but have the logic in my head for the below tasks. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with the code:

To print the CountDistinct of each column of the table.

Let's say I have 10 columns in the table. If I create a query for each column to get the result is going to take a lot of time. So the logic I want to apply is to loop over each column and print count distinct on the results. Once done, I can copy and paste the same on a document in one go.

Comment: What is your question? Are you seeking yes and no over the approach you have mentioned? Also, what database are you using as you have tagged multiple databases?

Comment: None loop. GROUP BY + 10 * COUNT(DISTINCT)

Comment: @Pankaj I am looking to get the code for the above task. I am using SQL query on Synapse for this task. Actually, I had to choose a minimum of 5 tags to submit my question. That's why I had chosen whatever was close to my question.

Comment: Please edit your tags to remove other databases, so it can properly reflect in for people tracking synapse tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.